# cant import routing modules in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, url-routing

i have tried importing routing classes like this :

```
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
```

but it seems they don't exist to be more specific "myapp/node_modules/Angular/router has no exported member Route" the same when i hover over "RouterModule" the same happens for many other modules.i'm using angular-cli for creting my project. is there any fix for this?

Comment: I have run into this as well in the past. attempt to re import router, you also could manually map router in you jsconfig, and lastly if all else fails I have had some luck with an npm install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the angular-cli so i created a project manually based on [angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and the problem was gone